# Why does the background for some elements extend across the width of the DIV and some don't?

Tags: html, css

I have a rather colorful background, and to make the text legible, it's set on a semi-transparent background. H1, P both show the background the full width of the divs. `span`s and `a`s however only show the background for where they are. This latter behavior is what I would prefer, definitely for the Headings, but also possibly for the paragraphs as well.

```
|-------------width of div-----------|
|{Header:BG fills whole div_________}|
|   {LINK}                           |
|{Paragraph:Same behavior as header_}|
|                       {SPAN}       |
|------------------------------------|
```

I'm using CSS strict HTML for preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `<h1>,<p>,<span>` and `<a>` is that the first two are `"display:block"` by default, while last two are `"display:inline"`.

Adding `"display:block"` property to your `<a>` and `<span>` should do it.

**Response to comment:**

I'll add a visual examle:

```
<div style="width:300px; border:1px solid #444">
  <div style="background:#999">This is a div</div>
  <a style="background:#999">This is a link</a>
  <h1 style="background:#999">This is a header</h1>
  <span style="background:#999">This is a span</span>
</div>
```

returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VSOB.jpg)

while

```
<div style="width:300px; border:1px solid #444">
  <div style="background:#999">This is a div</div>
  <a style="background:#999; display:block">This is a link</a>
  <h1 style="background:#999">This is a header</h1>
  <span style="background:#999; display:block">This is a span</span>
</div>
```

returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiLfF.jpg)

You are trying to achieve that, right?

Comment: Maybe my brain is just being dumb today, but I'm looking more towards making headlines, and possibly paragraphs behave like the span does... However, if I do `display:inline` on those however, everything clumps together unless I put a `div` or something in between. Might something like `inline-box` work?